# How do I add an attribute to my views in Android that shows up in Hierarchy Viewer?

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, hierarchyviewer

I'm trying to examine the screens of my Android app to confirm a certain font is used for each bit of text on each screen. The font varies (DIN, Proxima Nova, etc.) and the style varies (bold, semi-bold, regular, etc.) and has to be looked up in the screen mock ups online in a tool used by graphics designers.

For the font style I can open the Hierarchy Viewer tool, click on the view, and check the font style property matches the requirements. How do I do this for the typeface? There is no typeface property visible in the hierarchy viewer.

Examining the source code is not definitive since typefaces are set by custom attributes on some views, in code for other views, and all screens are composed of a large mix of fragments, custom views, and normal views. Looking at the screen is not definitive since it's tough for me to tell between the different fonts.